# Specifying class path for individual jar

Tags: java, ant, selenium-grid

I was trying to setup Selenium Grid and instead of using ant configuration available with Selenium Grid download I continued using my ant configuration.

For ant users who are not aware of Selenium Gird - it is a java lib which lets UI tests be distributed on different system specified in one "yml" file. Herein I can start one hub machine and which in turn can ctrl browser on different slave machines.

Ant configuration which I was using -

```
<target name="setClassPath">
    <path id="classpath_jars">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </path>
    <pathconvert pathsep=":" property="test.classpath"
        refid="classpath_jars" />
</target>

<target name="launch-hub" description="Launch Selenium Hub" depends="setClassPath">
    <java classname="com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.hub.HubServer" 
        classpathref="classpath_jars" 
        fork="true" 
        failonerror="true">

        <sysproperty key="http.proxyHost" value="${http.proxyHost}" />
        <sysproperty key="http.proxyPort" value="${http.proxyPort}" />
        <sysproperty key="https.proxyHost" value="${https.proxyHost}" />
        <sysproperty key="https.proxyPort" value="${https.proxyPort}" />

    </java>
 </target>
```

Now while using this configuration, my hub always starts with "yml" file which is available in "selenium-grid-hub-standalone-1.0.8.jar" instead of considering the "yml" file which I defined on my project root.

Following this I changed the ant configuration as following, which is available in Selenium Grid distribution -

```
<path id="hub.classpath">
    <pathelement path="${basedir}/"/>
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib">
        <include name="selenium-grid-hub-standalone-1.0.8.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="launch-hub" description="Launch Selenium Hub">
    <java classname="com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.hub.HubServer"
          classpathref="hub.classpath"
          fork="true"
          failonerror="true" >

        <sysproperty key="http.proxyHost" value="${http.proxyHost}"/>
        <sysproperty key="http.proxyPort" value="${http.proxyPort}"/>
        <sysproperty key="https.proxyHost" value="${https.proxyHost}"/>
        <sysproperty key="https.proxyPort" value="${https.proxyPort}"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

And now when I start the hub, it consider the "yml" file which is defined in my project root and not the one which is available in "selenium-grid-hub-standalone-1.0.8.jar" file.

I am no ant aficionado but I find both configuration almost similar, wherein first configuration has dependency on target while other uses the "pathid". Any one who could throw light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the difference is that the classpath in the second example includes your project root dir:

```
<pathelement path="${basedir}/"/>
```

whereas the first one does not.

Comment: Actually property lib.dir is defined as -                          <property name="lib.dir" value="${basedir}/lib" /> hence it has reference of basedir, I could post entire build, but that would make it looooong post

Comment: But `${basedir}` itself is not on classpath in the first example, right? This is the dir where the yml file you want to be used is, if I understand you.

Comment: I'm not, but it was nice of you to say it :)